# What are the GOP's Alternatives to Obamacare

Tags: united-states, healthcare

Given the GOP's objection to Obamacare, I have a question about its alternatives.

Assuming that we are unwilling to repeal the [Emergency Medical Treatment and Active Labor Act](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emergency_Medical_Treatment_and_Active_Labor_Act), which mandates that hospitals provide coverage to anyone who comes to their doors regardless of ability to pay,

- What would the GOP/right like to do about the healthcare situation in the US?
- How would they change Obamacare to be more in line with the conservative viewpoint?
- If the GOP were actually to repeal it, what would they put in its place?

Comment: They don't quite know yet: http://thehill.com/homenews/house/195689-boehner-obamacare-replacement-bill-coming

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about prognostication of an event that is not going to happen.  The GOP position is that the government should not be involved in healthcare management.

Comment: @Chad That is one of my primary reasons for posting the question. The government is involved with healthcare through the Emergency Medical Treatment and Active Labor Act.  Assuming the GOP isn't in support of repealing this act (not a very popular position), how would they bring the healthcare laws more in line with their views?  It is a practical question; not an ideological one.

Comment: @ChrisMueller - That is off topic for this SE.

Comment: The last thing the internet needs is another political discussion forum.  I am sure you can go find one of the many others outh there

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**They would likely pass something like the [American Health Care Reform Act of 2013](http://beta.congress.gov/bill/113th/house-bill/3121) to replace Obamacare**

This would among other changes:

- Repeal Obamacare.
- Allow everyone to deduct healthcare expenses, not just those who itemize (helps the bottom 40% of households).
- Treats High Deductible Healthcare Plans (HDHP) as Health Savings Accounts (HSA).
- Increases HSA maximum contributions.
- Limits non-economic damages to $250,000 for medical malpractice.

This is more inline with the GOP/Conservative viewpoint. They do not believe that the federal government has the right to force you to purchase healthcare coverage.

Comment: I think the final paragraph might be too strong, as the individual mandate was originally supported by the Heritage Foundation and Republican governor Mitt Romney. It seems that there may not be consistent consensus on the Republican viewpoint in that area. Still, it pretty much answers the question, so +1.

Comment: @Avi, "originally supported" != "currently supported"

Comment: Though I recognize the Heritage Foundation and Romney have spoken out against the Affordable Care Act, I don't recall that either have denounced their own proposals.

Comment: @Avi, "They do not believe that the federal government has the right to force you to purchase healthcare coverage." QFT. [Mitt](http://abcnews.go.com/blogs/politics/2011/02/mitt-romney-no-apology-for-individual-health-care-mandate/), "the federal government [...] impose it on all of the states. That is one of the reasons why this bill is unconstitutional," and [Heritage](https://www.askheritage.org/is-president-obamas-individual-health-care-mandate-constitutional/), "not a constitutionally permissible activity by the federal government." **Still think the final paragraph is too strong?**

Comment: eh, I guess the qualifier that they feel that is not in the domain of the federal government specifically sufficiently qualifies the statement then.

Comment: I prefer the "What healthcare you choose or your employer chooses to provide is none of the governments business" Plan.

Comment: A proper conservative viewpoint would note that the total amount of something that people can afford cannot possibly exceed the total amount that is produced; any action which makes something more affordable for someone, without increasing the amount produced, will make it less affordable for someone else who, likely as not, needed it more. Programs which encourage supply gobble up revenue, but they at least have the potential to increase the total amount of the subsidized good that people will be able to afford. Demand subsidies, by contrast, nearly always on net make goods *less* affordable.

Comment: The total flip-flip the Right did on individual mandates as soon as a Democrat took the proposal, does not prove they have a new, consistent viewpoint. Quite the opposite, actually.